Movie about a boy and a dog
There is not much I remember about the movie, since I've seen it as a kid (15-20 years ago). I've seen it in a cinema, so it couldn't have been a TV series. It was about a boy and a dog. At the beginning of the movie, the boy was in a forest (near a lake?) and was attacked by a bear. The dog either protected the boy or just barked at it allowing the boy to climb a nearby tree. I think some time later the boy was still sitting on the tree and it started raining hard.
The only other scene the I remember from the movie involved the boy and his family moving far away and leaving the dog behind. I think the dog actually followed them and a big part of the movie was about the the dog trying to reach his master (the boy). I vaguely remember that at the end of the movie the dog tired and dirty reached the boy and his family.
Does anyone know what movie is this? Hopefully I'm not combining scenes from different movies here.

..... and when were you a kid?  Could this be one of the many Lassie movies / tv shows?

@iandotkelly I've seen it in a cinema back when I went to grade school, which must have been 15-20 years ago. It was definitely a movie and not a TV show. I hope the bear part is characteristic enough to help identify the movie.

sounds like Homeward Bound http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107131/

@DustinDavis Although I don't remember there being other pet animals and the animals talking, but this actually might be it. I'll have to get a copy of the move and have a look. You could probably post this as an actual answer rather than only a comment.

@DustinDavis It wasn't Homeward Bound, but Bingo as pointed by John Smith Optional.

@MarcinHabuszewski which is why I didn't post as an answer. Glad you found it.

I'm 100% this was actually Bingo, which was an incredibly poor derivative of Lassie...




It features all the plot lines you mention, as well as the earworm of a song playing throughout...

...The next day after that, Chuckie wakes up to find himself completely
  naked and all his clothes have been hung up on the washing line
  (including Bingo's collar). He eventually finds Bingo and thanks him
  for saving his life, and that they'll be friends for life. Bingo finds
  a fish for Chuckie to eat but encounter a bear in the process.

after this initial rescue...

But he misses Chuckie's car as it drives off to their new home. Chasing the car, Chuckie's parents spot him, and they drive away.

The rest of the film is about Bingo travelling to this 'new home' to be with Chuckie.

Was a second away from posting the same answer. :) It's worth noting that the bear scene is near a lake and the boy climbs up a tree and stays there with the dog all night (it doesn't rain, but the boy's wet from the lake and you can hear water in the background).

I watched the trailer and this is the movie I was looking for. Thanks!
